Double-slit experiment with accelerating charged particles
As I understand, charged particles that are accelerated will emit photons.
I assume that it is possible to set up a double-slit experiment where the particles, say electrons, are accelerated from when they leave the source until they hit the screen, for example by adding an anode on the other side of the screen. This way the electrons will emit photons as they move from the source to the screen, and possibly also when passing the double-slit.
What would an external photon detector see when running such an experiment with and without the double-slit installed, will there be a difference in the received signal? And if so, would it be possible to interpret the difference in any meaningful way?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
